# Unable to create new maven project using jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype

Tags: java, maven, jersey, maven-archetype

I am a newbie to jersey and maven.  I am trying to create a new maven project based on the jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype, using Eclipse (Luna).

When I go to create the project, I select the "jersey-quickstart-webapp" archetype.  Eclipse finds this archetype in the "Maven Central" catalog:

[image: Adding Jersey-quickstart-webapp]

However, when I go to create the project, I get the message:
[image: error message after creating project]

I don't understand why I am getting this.  The archetype exists in the central repository at http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/archetypes/jersey-quickstart-webapp/2.14/

and Eclipse can find it when I search for it using the create new project wizard.

I have also tried to create the project from this archetype using the command line:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DarchetypeArticfactId=jersey-quickstart.webapp -DarchetypeVersion=2.2
```

When I do this, the project is created; however, when I import it, I get the following error appearing in my POM file:
[image: error in POM file]

so it cannot download the dependency:

`<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>`

When I look in my {homepath}.m2 directory, the contents of the jersey-quickstart-webapp download appear to be there.  However, the contents of the {homepath}.m2\repository\org\glassfish\jersey\jersey-bom\2.14 download just shows a .lastUpdated file, with no content.  The .lastUpdated file has the contents:

`http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.error=Could not transfer artifact org.glassfish.jersey\:jersey-bom\:pom\:2.14 from/to central (http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)\: Access denied to http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.14/jersey-bom-2.14.pom. Error code 403, Forbidden
@default-http\://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/.lastUpdated=1419265078216`

I don't understand why this import is failing.  When I open a browser and go to 
http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/glassfish/jersey/jersey-bom/2.14/jersey-bom-2.14.pom
I can view the contents no problem.

I am not sure how to move forward on this and create a new project based on the jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype.  I appreciate any suggestions.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add Java.net repo in your app:
`<project ...>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net</id>
            <url>https://maven.java.net/content/repositories/public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>`

Comment: for IntelliJ, you can specify the repo URL when creating a new module via Maven

Answer (score 0):

Check here:
https://books.sonatype.com/m2eclipse-book/reference/repository-sect-repo-view.html

In principle it's central repository which should be updated.